# MySQL: Strategy to move data to another server

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

So my situation is as follows:

There is a single Master-Slave Replication on a MySQL 5.5 basis.
The master use a small SSD as data partition. 
Therefore I want to clean a certain Inno Table (lets call this table `MasterA`) and move old (datediff < -2) rows to another database on the slave (`SlaveA`) with more space on the SATA-HDD.

The problem gets interesting as in some cases I need to access data from `SlaveA`. 
So I think it would be the best if an event triggers a transaction like this:

```
INSERT INTO SlaveA SELECT * FROM MasterA WHERE datediff(created, now()) < -2;
DELETE FROM MasterA WHERE datediff(created, now()) < -2;
```

But how could I access `SlaveA` from the master? I already tried the federated engine, but it gets stuck with the `read_only` option activated on the slave and the super privilege for the user accessing the federated table.

Maybe the event should only call the copy query on the slave, but how to delete the rows on the master afterwards?

There should be other options than installing MySQL 5.6 and use another partition for the `SlaveA` table on the master.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external daemon process (with handles to both databases) could accomplish what you are looking for but it is not a very clean solution.

If you did have a single handle with access to both databases a trigger would be a viable solution. I would change your code to use a [MySQL user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) setting it in the first statement and use it in the second statement.

On the other hand I would question why you think you need the write master on a SSD. Insert queries are normally a lot cheaper than delete queries. If you make sure all the reads are against the slaves the master should have very minimal latency. I would recommend putting it on SATA HDD and not running delete quires against it. Then you don't have to create a custom trigger; [MySQL's built in replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) should work just fine.

Comment: I was afraid that there is no clean built-in solution in MySQL.

Comment: The slave was intended as a plain backup, but since the requirement changes your proposal of distributing queries among master and slave became more and more valid.

Comment: I highly recommend doing backup through MySQL's built in replication. Also taking mysqldump from a slave (as to not decrease the performance of the master) is a good practice.